# Rails - I want user uploaded images to have to be approved before being made public in main database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, filtering

It is a rails app where Users upload images (S3). User images are displayed in a carousel (one at a time) at random on the home page. I want to quarantine the uploaded images from entering the carousel until they have been approved by an admin account.

As a consideration, I also want to impose our url logo in the same place on every photo.

Comment: There are a few ways to deal with this.  I would allow the initial uploads to go into an S3 bucket separate from the one being used for the carousel.  Then I would have upload be moved into another bucket once approved to be used by the carousel. You can also add your watermark when the image is approved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your console:

```
rails g migration add_approved_to_images approved:boolean
```

Change the default value in the migration file:

```
add_column :images, :approved, :boolean, default: false
```

Add an `approved` scope:

```
# Image model
scope :approved, -> { where approved: true }
scope :pending_approval, -> { where approved: false }
```

In the home page's controller:

```
def home_page_method
    @images = Image.approved.sample(5) # selects 5 images at random
end
```

Create an admin interface to approve images...

**Update (auto approve admin images)**

In your console:

```
rails g migration add_user_to_images user:belongs_to
```

Models:

```
# Image
belongs_to :user
before_create :auto_approve_admin_image

# scopes from earlier... etc.

private

def auto_approve_admin_image
    self.approved = true if self.user.is_admin?
end
```

&

```
# User
has_many :images

def is_admin?
    self.admin # the boolean user column that defines an admin
end
```

Comment: Is there a way to set this up so that photos uploaded by an admin are default: true (approved) ? thanks.

Comment: @Shaomai888 I've updated the answer

Comment: Thank you it is appreciated greatly.